# Display format "dynamic" in c

Tags: c, format, display

Usually I develop in PHP. But for a project I have to develop a small program in C (using Visual Studio on Windows).
I need to display values ​​on the screen (in the final version I write to a file).
Among the 3 values ​​there is a value (the C value in my example) that I need to see displayed as a character or as a number.

Example :
valueA = 65 | valueB = 10 | valueC = 80 => I want display A - 10 - P
valueA = 65 | valueB = 78 | valueC = 80 => I want display A - N - P

So I created this code and it works (I used static variables for a test code)

```
// Initialization
unsigned char valueA = 65;
unsigned char valueB = 10;
unsigned char valueC = 80;
unsigned char formatDisplay[25] = { 0 };
unsigned char formatA = 'c';
unsigned char formatB = 'c';
unsigned char formatC = 'c';

// If Character NOT Human Readable
if (valueB < 33)    formatB = 'd';

// Determination Format Display
sprintf(formatDisplay, "\n%%%c - %%%c - %%%c", formatA, formatB, formatC);

// Display Values
printf(formatDisplay, valueA, valueB, valueC);
```

But isn't there any simpler...?
I develop in C and not in C++

In the above question and example I only have 3 values ​​including 1 value with a variant display but I can later have more values ​​and more variant display.

Comment: If you only need to make `formatB` dynamic, you don't need `formatA` and `formatC`. But other than that, I don't think there's a simpler way.

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code ASCII codes. Use `if (!isgraph(valueB))`

Comment: Only the second format specifier is either `%d` or `%c`, the other ones are fixed, so `sprintf(formatDisplay, "\n%%c - %%%c - %%c", formatB);` should do the job

Comment: I mean, what stops you from doing: `const char *fmt = (valueB < 33) ? "\n%c - %d - %c"  : "\n%c - %c - %c"; printf(fmt, ...);` seems to me like you're over engineering your solution with that `sprintf`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thank you for your answer. In my example, I gave a single value to process, but I may need to have several values ​​to process. For example valueB (as in the example) but also value D, value F, etc.

Comment: @Barmar Thank's a lot for this fonction. I do not know.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Please make this an actual answer for future viewers.

Comment: @Juan then you need to re-formulate your question because it is really unclear. Do you need to cover *all* the possible combinations for each variable or is it just a single variable that you are concerned with? Both your question and your example show the second case. *"Among the 3 values ​​there is a value (the C value in my example) that I need to see displayed as a character or as a number."* - you need to reformulate.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I'm sorry but yes I took an example with 3 values ​​of which 1 can be displayed differently while I can have X values ​​with Y values ​​to be displayed differently. This is why I did not opt ​​for a solution where I can change the entire character string but only one element of the string.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you for your comment because indeed when I know that a display is fixed I can indeed treat it more simply

Comment: And thank you all for your replies.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I edited my question to clarify that I could have multiple values ​​with variable display. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using all the comments and answers I got, I answer my question, if it can help someone one day :).
With an example with 4 values ​​including 2 with variable display (B and D in the case below).

```
// Initialization
unsigned char valueA = 65;
unsigned char valueB = 10;
unsigned char valueC = 80;
unsigned char valueD = 85;
unsigned char formatDisplay[30] = { 0 };
unsigned char formatB = 'c';
unsigned char formatD = 'c';

// If Character NOT Human Readable
if (!isgraph(valueB))   formatB = 'd';
if (!isgraph(valueD))   formatD = 'd';

// Determination Format Display
sprintf(formatDisplay, "\n%%c - %%%c - %%c - %%%c", formatB, formatD);

// Display Values
printf(formatDisplay, valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD);
```